# "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined" in simple component

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader

I'm trying to start from basics in vuejs+webpack development.

I created a demo project here: https://github.com/Demian87/vue-test

It builds fine, but after launch I recieve an error from titile to console and my component in index changes to

```
<!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->
```

I'm using package.json from demo project for vuejs+webpack. I took webpack.config from there also, but I still get that error and nothing works.

Any ideas about the error reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your component lacks `name`:

```
export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data: function() {
        return {
            greeting: 'Привет всем!'
        }
    }
}
```

I rewrote main.js as

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Hello from '../components/hello.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        hello : Hello
    }
})
```

Also, there is a typo in template: `{{ greetings }}` instead of `{{ greeting }}`.

Comment: Thanks! Added name, but the code still doesn't work with the same error =(

Comment: Thanks! that helped! Why not using `import Hello from 'vue-loader!./components/hello.vue';`

Comment: @Demian, I don't know, what construction with `vue-loader!` in import should do.

Comment: This construction says webpack to use vue-loader instead of vue or anything else. I found such a recomendation in a tutorial.